# subdomain pointing to IP address of GCE

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a problem that I've been unable to solve for almost 2 months. I have set up:

- subdomain in GoDaddy account, I created `A` record and point it to the IP address.

Address of my GCE instance... I think my Nginx configuration is okay. My problem is that when I visit my site URL, it will show the IP address, not the `mysubdomain.example.com`. I don't want my IP address to be shown I want the subdomain name in the URL visible in the browser. My doubt is the `.htaccess` of my laravel application that causes the IP address to always show in the URL.

In Go Daddy account this is how I create in dns management.

```
type=A,
Host=mysubdomain,
Point to=i.p address,
ttl=1.
```

also below there is forwarding section in subdomain, I click add button, I         input mysubdomain,  forward to http://i.p address,forwrd  type=permanent(301),settings= forward only

This is the Nginx configuration in my server GCE

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    root /var/www/pro1/public/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name mysubdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri /index.php =404;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;    
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params; 

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying there is an _external redirect_ (ie. 3xx status) from the subdomain to the IP address? There's nothing in your `.htaccess` (or Nginx) files that would "expose" the IP address. How have you created the "subdomain in GoDaddy account"? You don't need to specifically "create a subdomain", you just create the `A` record.

Comment: @w3dk, I created in DNS management, type=A,Host=mysubdomain,Point to=i.p address, ttl=1 thats it. also below there is forwarding section in subdomain, I click add button, I input mysubdomain,  forward to http://i,p address,forwrd type=permanent(301),settings= forward only

Comment: "thats it" - That should be it. But you created a redirect as well - that's the problem! An `A` record and a _redirect_ are two completely different things, although with an `A` record in place (to an external server), you wouldn't necessarily expect to see the redirect - but that's probably down to GoDaddy's implementation. (You will need to clear your browser cache after deleting the redirect.)

Comment: @w3dk, so I will delete the forwarding section that I added, so A record is enough ?..thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, delete the "forwarding section" (ie. "redirect"). I've added that as an answer.

Comment: Ok I deleted now the forwarding section...I also delete the A record and I  created again the A record just to make sure...does this will take time to effect ?

Comment: You didn't need to delete the "A record". But, providing you've added the same as before then hopefully nothing will need to happen, so you should be good to go. (Ordinarily, DNS changes can take upto 48 hours to propagate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also below there is forwarding section in subdomain, I click add button, I         input mysubdomain, forward to `http://i.p` address, forward  type=permanent(301),settings= forward only

That's the problem. You don't need an *external redirect* when you've already configured an `A` record! These are two different things.

(Although with an A record in place (to an external server), you wouldn't necessarily expect to see the redirect - but that's probably down to GoDaddy's implementation?)

Delete the redirect ("forwarding section").

You will need to clear your browser cache, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached hard by the browser (this is the same for any user that has visited your site).

Comment: Thank you so much I tried view in mobile device.. before It always show i.p address, now the subdomain name is shown...thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it should be a redirect at the Laravel application level.
No nginx rules look to be doing this, and.. you seem confused; nginx doesn't take care of .htaccess files. Take a look at [this](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess), for instance.

Comment: yes it redirect to my application with no problem, only bothers is the url it will show i.p address like this, `http://xxx.xx.xxx`...I want like this `http://mysbudomain.mymaindomain.com`

Comment: ok, you confirm what i said. BUT if you don't share any of the application's details, we can't help you further. And more, i'm a sysadmin, and this is the typical issue where i point the finger to the developer and say: "Hey mate, this is YOUR fault!" :)

Comment: Hi, @Marco, I really need help people like you...ok, what application details you needed  so that I can post...thank you in advance

Comment: I update my post in configuring dns managemente in go daddy